Java error for "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED"
I am getting the below error :
Failed to initialize MemoryUtil. Was Java started with `--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED

while running my spring boot application where I have Apache arrow dependency in pom.xml :
My pom.xml is :

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
            <artifactId>arrow-vector</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.arrow/arrow-memory-netty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
            <artifactId>arrow-memory-netty</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Now I added the --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED command as VMArguments while starting my application at local and it worked for me.
How should I handle it for my server while deploying this application?
Its a blocker to me

Removing arrow dependency since it was not needed as of now but still no luck

added these properties in application.properties as  below :
 spec.containers[0].env[0].name=JAVA_OPTS
 spec.containers[0].env[0].value=--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED




From the way your question is worded, it's not clear whether you've solved your problem or not. What you're running into is Java JPMS and Arrow's recent migration to it. You might find the information you need in https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/install.html.

My issue is not resolved and the two pointers that I have shared are those which I tried but still no luck.
Thank you for the reference you provided. I tried that source earlier too but no luck

I think I got the reason why I keep getting this error. This is a scenario related with Snowflake also. When using snowflake we need to add this [property to our VM Arguments and similarly while deploying to our server configurations file also.
It's fixed for me now!
Thank you folks!

That makes sense. Can you post a detailed solution in case it helps someone else?
